# How to reduce computation time in reading .csv in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I am working with `.csv` files of big dimension (around `300MB` each). Each file corresponds to a simulation scenario for which I have to do some stats. This is my way to treat them:

```
ia = [[[0 for col in range(500)] for row in range(len(xv)) for x in range(len(bite)) ]  for y in range(len(gamma))]
ra = [[[0 for col in range(500)] for row in range(len(xv)) for x in range(len(bite)) ]  for y in range(len(gamma))]
ic = [[[0 for col in range(500)] for row in range(len(xv)) for x in range(len(bite)) ]  for y in range(len(gamma))]
rc = [[[0 for col in range(500)] for row in range(len(xv)) for x in range(len(bite)) ]  for y in range(len(gamma))] 
    stat = 50
    for i in range(0,len(xv)):
        for j in range(0,len(bite)):
            for k in range(0,len(gamma)):
                folder = '/data_%.4f_%.1f_%.1f_%.1f_%f,%.2f/'%(xv[i],R0, mu, tau, bite[j],gamma[k]);
                Ia = [] ## 
                Ra = [] ## 
                Ic = [] ## 
                Rc = [] ## 
                for s in range(0,stat):
                    f = path+folder+'run_%d.csv'%s
                    df = pd.read_csv(f, names=['t', 'id', 'S','E','I','R','Sm','Em','Im'],header=0)
                    df0 = df.groupby(df.t).sum()
                    Ia.append(df0.I)
                    Ra.append(df0.R)
                    df0 = df.groupby(df.t).apply(lambda column: (column != 0).sum())
                    df0=df0.fillna(0)
                    Ic.append(df0.I)
                    Rc.append(df0.R) 

            Ia = pd.DataFrame(Ia)
            Ra = pd.DataFrame(Ra)
            Ic = pd.DataFrame(Ic)
            Rc = pd.DataFrame(Rc)
            ia[i][j][k] = np.median(Ia)
            ra[i][j][k] = np.median(Ra)
            ic[i][j][k] = np.median(Ic)
            rc[i][j][k] = np.median(Rc)
```

However this process is quite slow and I am wondering if there is a fastest solution to read them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things that might help:

For these lines

```
ia = [[[0 for col in range(500)] for row in range(len(xv)) for x in range(len(bite)) ]  for y in range(len(gamma))]
```

since you're just creating a multidimensional list of zeros, you can have:

```
ia = [[[[0] * 500] * (len(xv) * len(bite))]] * len(gamma)
```

instead of having to call range so many times.

For

```
for i in range(0,len(xv)):
    for j in range(0,len(bite)):
        for k in range(0,len(gamma)):
```

and `for s in range(0,stat):`

use `xrange` instead of `range`.

Also, if possible, change ia, ra, ic, and rc to a single layred dict instead of nested so you can use tuples as keys instead of accessing nested dicts:

```
ia[(i, j, k)]  # as apposed to ia[i][j][k]
```

You probably won't see much as speed up for this when setting the values of the dict, but you will likely see better performance when accessing the dict this way.

Comment: It gives an error `ia[(i, j, k)] = np.median(Ia) TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`

Comment: My bad, I thought you were using a dict for ia and the other ones. In this case, don't use the tuple.